# How to share text with image on flutter excluding icons?

Tags: flutter

I am currently able to share the text on top of the image using share package but I want to share the image and text along with it without my icons of refresh and share. Couldn't find any answers for this. Have used multiple share packages but couldn't achieve the expected result.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage("${imgUrl}$count"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder<Advice>(
          future: advice,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                      child: FadeTransition(
                        opacity: _animation,
                        child: Text(
                        snapshot.data!.adviceText,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'quoteScript'),
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.white),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            setState(() {
                              _controller.reset();
                              _controller.forward();
                              count++;
                              advice = fetchAdvice();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Share.share("Here's an advice for you: ${snapshot.data!.adviceText}");
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

This is the text and image widget. Can be shared with the dynamic text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHARE:** The best way I think is to use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package to capture the widget which contains both image and text that you need to share, then share it as a picture with [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package.

For instance:

```dart
// Create a controller
ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

[...]
// Wrap the widget which you want to capture with `Screenshot`
 Screenshot<Widget>(
            controller: screenshotController,
            child: Container(
               child: [...]
            ), 
          ),
[...]

// Create a method to take a screenshot and share it
// This method I get from my project, so you can modify it to fit your purpose
Future<void> shareScreen(String title, String name) async {
  final screenShot = await screenshotController.capture();

  if (screenShot != null) {
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/$name').create();
    await file.writeAsBytes(screenShot);

    await Share.shareFiles(<String>[file.path], subject: title, text: name);

    file.delete();
  }
}
```

Then replace the `Share.share` method in the below example with the `shareScreen` method just created above.

---

**HIDE BUTTON:** You can create a new variable like `bool isSharing = false;` to control the visible state of those 2 buttons. The important part is the `Share.share` method must be an `async` method to make the code works because it needs `await` to know when the share action is done.

For instance:

```dart
[...]
           if (!isSharing) // <--- Add this line
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        _controller.reset();
                        _controller.forward();
                        count++;
                        advice = fetchAdvice();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white),

                    // And modify here <---
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() => isSharing = true); // Hide the buttons
                      await Share.share(
                          "Here's an advice for you: ${snapshot.data!.adviceText}");
                      setState(() => isSharing = false); // Show the buttons
                    },
                    
                  ),
                ],
              ),
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is the second part actually. First I need to share the text on top of the background image.

Comment: Sorry for the missing answer, I have updated it @Amal

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it's too much to ask but can you share the code for capturing and sharing that file also ? I am really new to this. If it's not too much to ask. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's a bit complex but I'll try to explain as simple as possible, you can look at the updated answer.

Comment: So I just have to call the method above on my share icon OnPressed() right ?

Comment: As I have mentioned at the bottom, you just need to replace the `Share.share` method with the `shareScreen` method.

Comment: Thank you also when I add the if statement it raises an error The element type 'Set<Row>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: Please do a search first or open the question in another thread because it relates to a different issue.

Comment: Yes I will research more but thanks a lot for your huge help.